# How to create a "real" iOS push notification from Firebase topic messages if the app is not running?

Tags: firebase, notifications, push, message

As far as I understand messages on subscribed topics are received through the socket connection.
So while the app is running in the background I could create local notifications and "fake" notification that pop up on the home screen and are visible in the notification center.
But is there a way to receive topic pushes if the app is closed/not running in the background?
I'm grateful for any kind of feedback as I couldn't find any documentation regarding that specific use case.

Just to clarify: I am talking about (subscribed) topic messages in firebase NOT the firebase messages. I am used to the generic iOS push notifications handling and the involved lifecycle methods. All I need to know is how firebase topic messages can be sent via apns notifications.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase Messaging you can send notifications so the app is closed (it must be installed), basically it is configured in the AppDelegate the methods and configuration according to your need, you can see more information here [Firebase Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=es-419#notifications_and_data_messages)

Comment: Please keep in mind I am talking about topic messages.

Answer (score 0):

No you can’t, setup your configration in apo delegate and firebase settings, when the app is offline firebase talked directly to the APN which called the nitification center in your iphone but you don’t have access on it during the application is closed.

Comment: are you sure the messages will be sent via apns if the app is offline? Because it wasn’t working when I tested.

Comment: yes, make sure of your App Config in firebase and update the certificates ".p12" with it's passwords and use the firebase testing message,
you can send notification from firebase website by adding the device token, if there is any error it will appear